# GORM constraints: validator for boolean fields

Tags: validation, grails, grails-orm

I'm trying to set a simple restriction on the field of the domain object using the closure in constraints but it does not work.

For example, I have three fields:

```
boolean organization1 = false
boolean organization2 = false
boolean organization3 = false
```

`organization3` field can be set only if `organization1` field is set:

```
class Organization {
    boolean organization1 = false
    boolean organization2 = false
    boolean organization3 = false

    static constraints = {
        organization1()
        organization2()
        organization3(validator:{organization3, organization -> return organization.organization1 ? true : false })
    }
}
```

Controller actions and GSP- views I get by using scaffolding. That's what happens:

[image]
[image]

How to properly set a restriction? I would be very grateful for the information. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I got it correctly, but I'd put the validator this way:

```
static constraints = {
    organization3 validator:{ org3, org -> !org3 || org3 && org.organization1 } 
}
```

Comment: Why `!org3 || org3 && org.organization1` and not `!org3 || org.organization1`?  It seems like evaluating org3 the second time is superfluous.  If it is false, the left hand side of the logical-or would have passed and the right hand side would never be evaluated.  If the right hand side is evaluated, you already know that org3 is true.  Isn't that right?

Comment: Jeff is right actually. I simply copied too much from your original code :)